# EF CodeFirst THT - Column 'Id' specified as part of this MSL does not exist in MetaDataWorkspace

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, table-per-type

I'm using a 'table-per-type' hierarchy in my code-first project (EF5).
My derived classes override the default primary-key name to clearly identify this relationship from a database point of view, like so:

```
/* change primary keys to Chair.ProductId and Table.ProductId */
modelBuilder.Entity<Chair>()
    .Property(x => x.Id)
    .HasColumnName("ProductId");

modelBuilder.Entity<Table>()
    .Property(x => x.Id)
    .HasColumnName("ProductId");
```

Using the following classes as example:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   /* generic product properties */
}

[Table("Chair")]
public class Chair : Product
{
     /* specific chair properties */
}

[Table("Table")]
public class Table : Product
{
     public virtual ICollection<Chair> Chairs {get; set;}

     /* specific table properties */
}
```

Which causes the following error on property Table.Chairs: **Column 'Id' specified as part of this MSL does not exist in MetaDataWorkspace**.

Which I kinda understand as EF probably didn't see that the PK of Chair Product was changed.. (and still assumes it's called 'Id') But I can't figure out how I instruct EF to use the alternate key.

Thx,

PS. Yes I know, if I don't change the names of the PK's it works... but can it be done using the EF Fluent API?

Comment: Found the solution 30min after I posted. All I needed to do was add the following:

    modelBuilder.Entity<Table>().HasMany(x => x.Chairs).WithMany().Map(m =>
                { 
                    m.MapLeftKey("TableId");
                    m.MapRightKey("ChairId");
                    m.ToTable("TableChairs");
                });
    
And everything was working as expected ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is some bug of EDMX model generator in Visual Studio.

To solve this do:

- remove particular table from EF.
- save EF and restart Visual Studio
- add particular table to the model again
- save and compile

I have Visual Studio 2015 udpate 3

Comment: I was about to post this question and answer until I found this. I would emphasize the restarting of Visual Studio. What a weird fix.

Comment: This solution seems to work for me but the problem is since I have to generate the table/model again(using dev db), it will add other stuff that i don't need(or not sure is in prod db) which could break production.

Comment: I think this is a legit bug on the EF generation or with VS. I already suspected something is not working correctly in my local machine because I added manually the column as posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950795/adding-a-new-column-to-an-existing-table-in-entity-framework/38795367#38795367 (an answer I posted a while back) by manually adding the column. To prove it, I ask my co-worker to add manually the columns in the edmx file. He checked-in code, got latest in my machine and the update works.

Answer (score 1):

I recently was searching for a fix to a similar error, but designing things **Database first**.  I post my finding here because this is where my search kept landing me.

I had **multiple similar errors, on build**.  What they really meant is that **my Model never built successfully**.

I was able to fix the issue by **removing and re-adding some table valued functions that had been modified in the database recently**.

**Most of the errors and details I could find where actually just red-herrings**; other than the concept that the model didn't build successfully; and having knowledge of things someone else was changing in the database helped.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing similar errors and had made some manual fixes to my edmx file, but Visual Studio was still reporting this warning.

Turns out it was a false warning and **clean/rebuild** got rid of the error. Spent hours trying to figure out what was wrong with the edmx file but never thought of giving it a run and checking if it was actually a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Posting your comment as an answer:

Add the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Table>().HasMany(x => x.Chairs).WithMany()
.Map(m => { 
 m.MapLeftKey("TableId"); m.MapRightKey("ChairId"); 
 m.ToTable("TableChairs"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same one. Looking at all this I thought something is off with visual studio I mean no software is perfect right, a minute later I found a typo in my code :-|