# Entity Framework - Problem to recognize JSON field of MySQL

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two fields in MySQL (I am not owner of this database but just using it write/read) that are of type 'JSON'. In my .Net c# project I have the DATABASE FIRST logic, the problem it is that it ignores these two fields with type 'JSON', and actually I don't know how can I make to recognize these fields to update them.

Comment: As a first shot you could try to read/write them as string or maybe binary fields.

Comment: I tried adding it in the class auto-generated by EF, but it still can't read data

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/14), you can do something like:

```
public JsonObject<string[]> Column { get; set; }
```

Alternatively [this docs](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/EF-JSON-Support.html) suggest you do:

```
// The JSON column
[Column(TypeName = "json")]
public string JObject { get; set; }
```

Comment: i tried both solutions, problem it's that i tried put a breakpoint but it never goes in action, meanwhile in others attributes it does

Comment: ok solved, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950795/adding-a-new-column-to-an-existing-table-in-entity-framework helped